# NHibernate different session lifetime per table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, session

I'm running a wpf app. With a nhibernate session you only have to query a table once and you can access it as many times as you like from cache.

But i like to cache some tables through the entire app because they almost never change, like users and usergroups. Should i use one session for the entire app or is there another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cache that NHibernate provides as part of the session is referred to as the first level cache.

For caching things longer than the duration of a session, you need to take a look at the [second level cache](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-cache).  NHibernate ships with implementations for several cache providers (memcached, SysCache, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an excellent article on how to configure the 2nd level cache using FluentNHibernate

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/06/16/fluent-nhibernate-and-the-2nd-level-cache/